# Show html link over flash object without using wmode="transparent"

Tags: flash, iframe, wmode

On my html page, I have an iframe where I load another html page. This inner html page contains a flash movie. The iframe occupies the whole space on page. On main page, I need to show an html link at bottom right, but above the flash movie (which is inside iframe).  I have set the position of html link to absolute. But this link goes back as flash object is in front.

I cannot use wmode="transparent", because if I use this, some required features will be removed from flash movie.

I tried the following:

1. Added an another empty iframe with same dimensions as my html link (to be shown over flash).
2. Set the position of this iframe to absolute and set it to right bottom so it is at same position of html link.

This started showing my html link over the flash object which is inside another iframe. But this works only in IE and Firefox. Chrome and Safari still hide my link.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks & regards,
Nadeem Ullah